# Bind vector to list of dataframes by value

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list of dataframes to which I would like to append a vector (appending one value of the vector to each dataframe in the list).

I would like select the lowest value of the vector and append it to the dataframe in the list with the highest value of `stdev` (while maintaining the order of the list). Below is an example solution to clarify!

UPDATE: list of dataframes now have multiple columns.

```
#Data
#list of dataframes
lst <- list(A = data.frame(stdev = 2,
                           V1 = 2),
            B = data.frame(stdev = 6,
                           V1 = 1),
            C = data.frame(stdev = 4,
                           V1 = 4))
lst

#Vetor
vec <- c(10,5,11)
vec
```

I can think of a long and inelegant solution of converting the list to a dataframe and ordering, binding, reordering, renaming..... much too complicated:

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)

df <- rbindlist(lst, idcol = "df_name") %>% 
  mutate(original_order = 1:n()) %>% 
  arrange(desc(stdev)) %>% 
  mutate(vec = vec[order(vec)]) %>% 
  arrange(original_order)
df

names <- df$df_name
names
lst1 <- split(df, seq(nrow(df)))
names(lst1) <- names
lst1
lst2 <- lapply(lst1, select, -c(df_name, original_order))
lst2


$A
  stdev V1 vec
1     2  2  11

$B
  stdev V1 vec
2     6  1   5

$C
  stdev V1 vec
3     4  4  10
```

This eventually gives me the correct result with the highest value of the vector appended to the lowest value of the list (in the original order) but is there a more elegant solution?

UPDATE: Credit to @akrun and @RonakShah for this solution (a merger of the two answers):

```
vec <- sort(vec, decreasing = TRUE)
inds <- order(sapply(lst, "[[", "stdev"))
Map(cbind, lst, vec = vec[order(inds)])
```

Thanks!

Comment: Will all the dataframes in `lst` have only one value ? What if there are multiple rows/columns in each ? How do you decide the highest value ?

Comment: So in this case all the dataframes in the list will only have one row but multiple columns so will need to be able to specify the column by variable name stdev. Updated question, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Map`

```
Map(cbind, lst[order(unlist(lst))], vec = vec[order(-vec)])[names(lst)]
#$A
#  stdev vec
#1     2  11

#$B
#  stdev vec
#1     6   5

#$C
#  stdev vec
#1     4  10
```

---

Or an update based on the update of data

```
Map(cbind, lst[order(unlist(lapply(lst, `[[`, "stdev")))],
       vec = vec[order(-vec)])[names(lst)]
#$A
#  stdev V1 vec
#1     2  2  11

#$B
#  stdev V1 vec
#1     6  1   5

#$C
#  stdev V1 vec
#1     4  4  10
```

Comment: Oh that's WAY nicer thanks! I tried a `Map` solution but had the indexing incorrect.

Comment: I may have made my minimal example too minimal. Indexing still an issue with `unlist` on `df` with multiple columns. Working on it, question updated.

Comment: @QAsena. Thanks, I updated the solution.  I thought you have only a single column

Answer (score 1):

We can extract the `stdev` column from `lst`, `order` them, use it to re-arrange `vec` and `cbind` to original `lst` using `Map`

```
inds <- order(sapply(lst, "[[", "stdev"))
Map(cbind, lst, vec = sort(vec, decreasing = TRUE)[inds])

#$A
#  stdev V1 vec
#1     2  2  11

#$B
#  stdev V1 vec
#1     6  1   5

#$C
#  stdev V1 vec
#1     4  4  10
```

Comment: That's nice Thanks! For some reason didn't quite work on my real data which has more than 3 dataframes in the list. Possibly `vec = sort(vec, decreasing = TRUE)[inds]` is not quite right? but it seems to work by merging the two answers, sort first then index:
`vec <- sort(vec, decreasing = TRUE)`
`inds <- order(sapply(lst, "[[", "stdev"))`
`Map(cbind, lst, vec = vec[order(inds)])`

Comment: @QAsena I see. I am not sure why it would not work on your real data but I am glad you were able to solve it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Haven't figured out why it didn't work yet.

Pulls correct indices: e.g., `inds <- c(4,3,5,1,2)`, `vec <- 1:5`, sort 1: `sort(vec, decreasing = TRUE)[inds]` sort 2: vec[order(inds)]

Cheers!